# Inbound call integration using twilio-client

Tags: twilio, twilio-click-to-call, twilio-sdk

I've successfully implemented outbound call functionality using Twilio Client. However, I'm encountering challenges with implementing inbound call functionality. Could you please assist with this? Below is the code for outbound calls. Your help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
<script>
import { Device } from 'twilio-client';

toggleMute() {
    this.muted = !this.muted;
    Device.activeConnection().mute(this.muted);
},

toggleCall: function() {
    if (!this.onPhone) {
        this.muted = false;
        this.onPhone = true;
        // make outbound call with current number
        // var n = '+' + this.countryCode + this.currentNumber.replace(/\D/g, '');
        this.connection = Device.connect({ number: this.callData.ProspNumber, callerID: this.user.Twilio });
    } else {
        // hang up call in progress
        Device.disconnectAll();
        this.$emit('hangupCall', false);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: What challenges?

Comment: I have a scenario where someone is calling from a mobile phone to a Twilio number, and I want to show in my web application that the incoming call is there. How can I do that?

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/sdks/javascript/twiliodevice#incoming-event can you not detect an incoming call using the incoming event?

Comment: No @evolutionxbox

Comment: Are you using taskrouter?

Comment: No, I am not using taskrouter.

Comment: Do you have a backend?

Comment: yes, backend in nodejs